# Modifying Structure's variable Data

Tags: c++, struct, queue

Front function of user defined Queue

```
template<class Type>
Type queueType<Type>::front()
{
    if(!isEmptyQueue());
    return list[queueFront]; 
}

int main()
{
    struct process
    {
        int burst;
    }pro;

    int tq=2;
    pro.burst=10;
    Queue<process> RR;  
    RR.enQueue(pro);  
    RR.front().burst=RR.front().burst - tq; 
}
```

when i try to run this line:

```
RR.front().burst=RR.front().burst - tq;
```

it gives the following error:

```
using temporary as lvalue [-fpremissive]
```

what is the reason behind this error? is there any else way to perform this setup? Please give me a better solution to perform this operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to use `front()` to modify the first element, it needs to return a reference to it, not a copy:

```
Type & front();
     ^
```

You'll also need to remove the spurious `;` after `if(!isEmptyQueue())`, and perhaps do something like throw an exception if it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

`front()` should return `Type&`. Otherwise the value to be returned is *copied* before actually returned.

```
template<class Type>
Type& queueType<Type>::front() { ... }
```